# Submitting Codenameone Build To AppStore

Tags: app-store, codenameone

I have completed alpha testing my app using the CN1 'Send IOS Debug Build' and QR-coding it onto my iphone. So i'm ready to load it onto the AppStore, but i don't have a Mac (but i do have the ITunes developer account and the apps certificates generated). 
Its just confirmation on the next steps.

The good people at Coursera produced a number of excellent tutorials, of which this one describes the steps i need to perform:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/codapps/lecture/F1B6x/video-how-to-distribute-your-app-on-apples-app-store-you-need-a-mac. I have failed in finding a CN1 badged tutorial on this (closest is the certificates generation).

But time and technology move on, so i wanted to check this was still accurate - do i still need to:

1. Install Application Loader from Itunes Connect onto a Mac? Is there a non-Mac approach? If not then i will use the http://www.macinthecloud service.
2. Take the. ipa and artwork file from the CN1 build server and apply that to the mac, and then follow the rest of the steps in that tutorial?

Please don't shoot me down for such a basic question. Once i get through this first app i'll be cooking. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a Mac is needed, but MacInCloud works fine. As you said, you use application loader to upload your .ipa file. That's all you need the Mac for, so uploading artwork and everything can be done through iTunes Connect from your PC. The icon that will show up on the phone screen is bundled into the app, and I think the artwork with the build may not be the right size, so you might have to generate an icon for the store listing and of course the screenshots.

Comment: Spot on James. I used the pay as you go MacInTheCloud service for just 30mins, which has Application Loader already installed, so sped things up. Connect to the CN1 server from there to down load the IPA file and then used the AL to load onto the store, as per the coursera video. Thanks very much.